# Fastest way to allow sendmail relay through smarthost?

Tags: linux, smtp, sendmail, smarthost

I only want sendmail to relay through my ISP's smtp server, nothing else. How do i set it up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have specified answer in the question itself. You can do that using

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.your.provider')dnl
```

Are you facing any problem using this. After editing `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` you should go to directory `/etc/mail`. Type `make` and then restart `sendmail` service for changes to take effect. Then send a test mail and see message headers (Received:) to see if configuration worked.

Comment: Make command will call m4 to parse sendmail.mc again and it will also build other databases like aliases if we have changed them.

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't doing anything more fancy with the cumbersome beast that is Sendmail then you could consider using [SSMTP](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSMTP) instead.

It's a relay-only MTA which is lightweight and couldn't be simpler to configure.

Comment: ah, thanks, hadn't done my research very well.. SSMTP was much easier!

Comment: _ssmtp_ is unmaintained...

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a huge favour and replace sendmail with either a modern mta like postfix or something more lightweight like ssmtp. I'm amzed that sendmail is still used voluntarily

Answer (score 2):

[Nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer), IMHO, is even easier to configure. 
Here is a quick howto:

```
apt-get install -y nullmailer
```

Edit this file:

```
nano /etc/mailname
```

- Enter your domain name, like mydomain.com
- Save

Edit another file:

```
nano /etc/nullmailer/remotes
```

- Enter your smtp server data: `[mysmtpserver.com] smtp --auth-login --user=[username]
  --pass=[password]`
- Save

[Source](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-04-22/configure-nullmailer-smtp-authentication)